# Как привязать выполнение процедуры к элементы в списке?

Tags: delphi

Использую компонент ListBox.

```
procedure TFUsers.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  QueryUsers.Connection := FConnection.MainConnection;
  QueryUsers.SQL.Clear;
  QueryUsers.SQL.Add('select login from users');
  QueryUsers.Active := True;
  QueryUsers.Open;
  for i := 0 to QueryUsers.RecordCount-1 do
  begin
    ListBox_ListUsers.AddItem(QueryUsers.FieldByName('login').AsString, ****);
    QueryUsers.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Там где звездочки ****. Как мне тут записать процедуру?

Answer (score 2):

```
ListBox_ListUsers.AddItem(QueryUsers.FieldByName('login').AsString, @MyProc);
```

Так?